# cmake: how to find a directory from glob expression

Tags: cmake, glob

My linux machine has directory /usr/local/include/vtk-8.2/
How can cmake find this directory using glob expression “vtk-8”?
I tried this:

```
file(GLOB result LIST_DIRECTORIES true RELATIVE /usr/local “*vtk-8*”)
```

But ${result} is empty.

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks!
(cmake version 3.23.0-rc1, ubuntu 20.08)

Comment: Why are you trying to glob VTK?? Use their `find_package` module!

Comment: I wish. ;-) but find_package(VTK) is not working for some reason. I compiled vtk-8.2 from source, did 'make install'. Yet find_package(VTK) sets VTK_LIBRARIES, but VTK_INCLUDE_DIRS is set blank. I don't know why. But file(GLOB) seems a brute-force way to find it.

Comment: Then _that_ is your real problem. Seriously, do not try to replicate the VTK find module. It's way too complex. You can ask a question here showing how you built and installed VTK and how `find_package` fails, or you can try the VTK official support forum, here: https://discourse.vtk.org/

Comment: Thanks, good point. But I also do want to understand how to use file(GLOB) properly.

Comment: You look for alternatives. Globbing is a well-known gotcha in CMake. `file(GLOB)` has _very_ few valid uses, mostly in `install(CODE)` scripts.

Answer (score 0):

> What am I doing wrong?

You are searching for `vtk-8` in current source directory. Search for them in `/usr/local` if you want to.

```
file(GLOB result LIST_DIRECTORIES true RELATIVE /usr/local /usr/local/*vtk-8*)
```

Comment: Thanks KamilCuk. So if glob pattern has no leading '/', then local directory is assumed? I.e. '/' must be hardcoded in the glob expression? It appears so, even though I couldn't find cmake's glob rules anywhere in the documentation.  Since actual subdirectory is /usr/local/include/vtk-8.1, then I had to specify glob expression as "/usr/local/*/*vtk-8*" to find it (i.e. "/usr/local/*vtk-8*" does not match, since subdirectory "include/" is in the actual path to the subdirectory.

Comment: `if glob pattern has no leading '/', then local directory is assumed?` The relative path is interpreted as relative to `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR`. Absolute path is... absolute. `then I had to specify glob expression as "/usr/local/*/*vtk-8*"` Yes, use `GLOB_RECURSE`, then `/usr/local/*vtk-8*` will recurse recursively into `/usr/local` searching for `*vtk-8*` (it does _not_ work like in shell).

Comment: Tried GLOB_RECURSE with glob expression "/usr/local/*vtk-8*" but result is blank. 
file(GLOB_RECURSE result /usr/local/*vtk-8*)

Comment: @Tomasso you forgot `LIST_DIRECTORIES true`, so it should be `file(GLOB_RECURSE result LIST_DIRECTORIES true /usr/local/*vtk-8*)` but you won't get what you expect. Just give up on these functions they are messy.